# Can Scala 3 union types "fix" the Map[String, Any] problem?

Tags: scala, union-types, scala-3

Idiomatic Scala code is as typesafe as possible. As a result, reflection is frowned upon and if you end up with `Any` in your static types you have a problem.

For example, the popular Circe library can without any boilerplate turn a `Map[String, String]` or a `Map[String, Int]` into JSON

```
Map("a" -> "b").asJson
Map("one" -> 1).asJson
```

but if you try to combine the two you end up with a `Map[String, Any]` and it cannot work with that.

```
Map("a" -> "b", "one" -> 1).asJson // BOOM (compile-time boom, of course, we are not animals)
```

In Scala 3, presumably the type will be `Map[String, String | Int]` ?

If so, is it now possible to implement methods like `asJson` (maybe using macros if necessary) that can figure out that each of the possible types in the union are "acceptable"?

(The Circe example was just that, an example, in real life you'd not have this Map in the first place, but a proper case-class, for a discussion on this aspect, see [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67344369/14955) that sparked this question)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/jvican/dijon/pull/202/files#diff-c9c1dd8be62fc74781763a4a6bd8672bf98fc16ce41755c06a3fcad7a5339c51R11-R18) is my attempt to make JSON AST using union types for the current version of Scala 3.

Comment: While union types will help in some cases, I do not think they will be the right tool to model this kind of things. Union types are affected by type erasure so things like `List[Int] | List[String]` will produce wrong results at runtime. Also, it still doesn't provide a correct way to limit the subset of types that are valid in JSON. And **ADT** is still the best way to model it; and maybe using the **magnet** or generic programming is the best way to produce a good ux.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like this is [inferred as `Map[String, Matchable]`](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RihpladFRdWozgLCUOI4CQ). Union types do not seem to be inferred by default.

Comment: Not sure if I'm interpreting your question properly, but I don't think you need union types. I made a basic implementation ([link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ypMw2a0zTHmx0HlAEBX2UA)) using just typeclasses and Scala 3's tuple consing.

Comment: @user: Yes, this is how it currently works more or less with PlayJSON or Circe. But it adds some extra boilerplate (new wrappers, new operators). Cannot just do `Map("a" -> "b", "one" -> 1).asJson` (something we *can* do if all values were Strings). Which, again, is totally fine for the problem at hand (JSON serialization). I was just wondering if there is a "more magic" way now.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez "still doesn't provide a correct way to limit the subset of types that are valid JSON". So what Andriy is trying with the JSONPrimitive and Rec types cannot be made to work? https://github.com/jvican/dijon/pull/202/files#diff-c9c1dd8be62fc74781763a4a6bd8672bf98fc16ce41755c06a3fcad7a5339c51R12

Comment: "Union types are affected by type erasure". Is this different from how type erasure already affects the `Map[String, String]` we have today? I imagine the hypothetical `toJson` function (which may be a macro) would use the compile-time union type to summon the typeclass instances it needs, just like it does now.

Comment: @user: "inferred by default". True, but you can manually type it at least: `Map("a" -> "b", "one" -> 1): Map[String, Int | String]` compiles

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted it inferred on its own. The version I showed above is pretty basic, and it could certainly be prettified and maybe made to look more like Circe's `asJson` (although a `Map` would not work, as those are homogeneous). A macro could certainly do this, although I'm not really sure how union types would be of use.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now. A plain `Map` being treated as a heterogenous map would need to have checks at runtime to use the correct typeclass instance, and it'd also be a bit complex.

Comment: I don't understand the need for runtime checks. It works statically for `Map[String, Int]` and for `Map[String, String]` today, so why cannot it be made to work for `Map[String, Int | String]` in the same way now that we have that new union type?

Comment: @Thilo ah so you didn't mean if union types could be used to model JSON but rather if a JSON library could work for union types; sorry for the confusion. I guess they could and they will probably do once **Scala 3** becomes more mainstream. - The two problems I see are, 1. Not sure if you can build instances inductively for union types the same way we do for heterogenous tuples. 2. I expect a lot of people to introduce bugs due type erasure, thus I would expect more conservative libraries like **circe** to put the support of union types behind some extra imports or even maybe some extra module

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk I like your link, perhaps post as an answer? Would be grateful if you could explain what `[A] =>> mutable.Buffer[A]` is.